# How to pass an arraylist from Java to xsl and access this individual arraylist elements in XSL?

Tags: java, xslt

I am passing an arraylist from Java to Xsl using transformer.setParameter.

```
ArrayList books=new ArrayList<String>;
transformer.setparameter("booksinXSL","books");
```

Now I need to access this array's elements in XSL.

```
<xsl:param name="booksinXSL">
```

Now If I use this line of code in XSL it throws an error:Invalid conversion of ArrayList to NodeSet.

```
<value-of select="$booksinXSL[0]">
```

but if I set it as the below line it prints the entire array [book1,book2] without any error

```
<value-of select="$booksinXSL">
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using? The reference to "NodeSet" in the error messaage suggests it's a 1.0 processor, but you have tagged the question XSLT-2.0. Note that mappings from Java types to XPath types are not defined by any standard, they vary from one XSLT processor to another.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I am using XSLT 1.0.

Comment: I've edited your question to remove the misleading xslt-2.0 tag. But it remains true that there are several Java-based XSLT 1.0 processors, and mapping from Java to XPath/XSLT types depends on which one you are using.

Comment: What **exactly** are the contents of the parameter? -- P.S. Note that in XSLT, nodes are numbered starting from 1, so `select="$node-set[0]"` will never select anything. But that's not likely the problem here, since you are getting an error.

Answer (score 2):

XSL does not have the concept on arrays defined, but you can define a variable to contain a set of nodes and then iterate through these nodes. You can see a useful example at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503086/does-xslt-have-any-concept-of-an-array) page.

Comment: Iteration is not possible as I mentioned in the question if u pass an array from java to xslt using transformer.setparameter method.

Comment: You need to iterate through the set of nodes after you have passed the array.